# Microsoft Dynamics NAV instance running after windows restart but not responding

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I've got issue with Microsoft Dynamics NAV instance.

We're restarting Windows server each night (I know that we probably shouldn't do it, but this is a separated topic and not the point of this question).

After windows server starts, SQL and Dynamics Nav instances are starting. Sometimes (1-2 times per month) Dynamics NAV instance is marked as 'Running', but actually doesn't respond (Web services are not working, RTC client cannot connect to this instance etc.). We have to restart Dynamics Nav instance manually once again in order to get it working correctly.

Did anyone have similar problems? We were looking into Windows Logs, but couldn't find anything interesting..

We also wonder if we shouldn't manage start of the services (SQL server, Dynamics Nav instances etc.) manually somehow instead of depending on the automatic start of everything after windows restart.

**Update:**
There is actually one error in the Windows Event Log which occures ONLY in days when Dynamics Nav instance is not started corretly:

> Server instance: XXXX
>
> Tenant ID:
>
> User:
>
> Type: System.AggregateException
>
> Message: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on
>   the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the
>   unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.
>
> HResult: -2146233088
>
> ---
>
> Type: System.BadImageFormatException
>
> Message: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
>
> StackTrace:
>
> ```
>  at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavLicense.NativeMethods.UnpackLicense(Byte[]
> ```
>
> license, Int32 licenseSize, StringBuilder header, Int32 headerSize)
>
> ```
>  at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavLicense.Create(Byte[] license, LicenseExpiredHandler licenseExpiredHandler)
>
>  at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavDatabaseSecurityAndLicense.get_License()
>
>  at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.WindowsLanguageDataProvider.IsAvailableLanguage(Int32
> ```
>
> languageId)
>
> ```
>  at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavEnvironment.FindSupportedLanguage(Int32
> ```
>
> languageId, Int32 defaultLanguageId)
>
> ```
>  at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavSession.Open(Boolean useUserPersonalization, Byte[] licenseToUse, Boolean
> ```
>
> allowAppsDisabledMode)
>
> ```
>  at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavTaskSchedulerHelpers.RunAsSystemSession(NavTenant
> ```
>
> tenant, Action`1 action)
>
> ```
>  at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavTaskScheduler.TaskRunInfo.InternalRun()
>
>  at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavTaskFactory.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RunTask>b__0()
>
>  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
>  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> ```
>
> Source: Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Ncl
>
> HResult: -2147024885

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest Delayed Start to help alleviate missing dependencies such as certificates OCSP validation without internet, etc. There should be Windows Logs saying the `The service has completed configuration and is ready.`

Service Auto-restart actions might help catch unexpected errors, but as it's `Running` I'm not sure it'll exactly apply to your situation.

The service tier should not be restarted nightly, as you've pointed out :). It might be easier to solve that issue, but I can't suggest anything without more information.

Also, which version of Dynamics NAV/Business Central?

Comment: That's Dynamics Nav 2016 and before you ask - yes, we're thinking about upgarding to BC or Dynamcis Nav 2018 at least :) I've put an update to the question with error from the events log.

Comment: That stack suggests its having trouble loading the license. It can either be stored within the database or at the sql server level -- perhaps there's a startup order issue between SQL and NAV? Tried Delayed Start on your NAV service and see whether that works.